# how to convert axis time from "HH:mm:ss.000Z" to "HH:mm:ss" format

Tags: java, time, wsdl2java

I have `startTime` field setter method which accepts only in  `org.apache.axis.types.Time`  and want to insert the time in "hh:mm:ss" format. but when I try to insert the date in hh:mm:ss format, always it returns axis time with default format hh:mm:ss:SSSZ. I just need to remove the **Z** from SSSZ axis time.

I have converted actual time to hh:mm:ss format using simpleDateformat conversion.

```
org.apache.axis.types.Time  
postedtTime = new org.apache.axis.types.Time ("12:15:36");          
acctTrnInfo_Type.setstartTime(postedtTime);
```

Please help.